# Looking for Informix4GL by Example header file 'fgicfunc.h'

Tags: c, header-files, informix, 4gl

I am working through the Informix4GL by Example cookbook.  Exercise 13 deals with creating external callable modules written in C.  The example code contains this line:

```
#include "fgicfunc.h"
```

But I cannot find this file or a description of its contents.  It is supposed to be related to the Informix database software product but I do not have this installed.  Does anyone here have that file; and if you do then can you provide me the contents?

Comment: ` It is supposed to be related to the Informix database software product but I do not have this installed` well, then install it?

Comment: It seems a little overkill to install an entire database software package just to get a single header file.  I am using `Aubit4GL` with `PostgreSQL` and just need this to complete the exercises in the `By Example` cookbook.  I since learned that Aubit4GL has an inline code feature, so perhaps this file is not needed.

Comment: With FourJs Genero we found that the need to add external callable modules written in C was reduced by the fact that we had added into the core product the functionality that Informix 4gl did not have.  So for example reading/writing files, random numbers, and more  was now in the core product and you no longer needed to maintain external c modules.   More often than not after a transformation we would have no external c modules needing to be maintained.  I can't speak for Aubit but you may find it is something you don't need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the copyright notice, etc, this is published when you install the I4GL p-code compiler.

```c
/**************************************************************************/
/*                                                                        */
/*  Licensed Materials - Property of IBM                                  */
/*                                                                        */
/*  "Restricted Materials of IBM"                                         */
/*                                                                        */
/*  IBM Informix 4GL                                                      */
/*  (c) Copyright IBM Corporation 2010 All rights reserved.         */
/*                                                                        */
/**************************************************************************/
/***************************************************************************
 *
 *                         INFORMIX SOFTWARE, INC.
 *
 *                            PROPRIETARY DATA
 *
 *      THIS DOCUMENT CONTAINS TRADE SECRET DATA WHICH IS THE PROPERTY OF 
 *      INFORMIX SOFTWARE, INC.  THIS DOCUMENT IS SUBMITTED TO RECIPIENT IN
 *      CONFIDENCE.  INFORMATION CONTAINED HEREIN MAY NOT BE USED, COPIED OR 
 *      DISCLOSED IN WHOLE OR IN PART EXCEPT AS PERMITTED BY WRITTEN AGREEMENT 
 *      SIGNED BY AN OFFICER OF INFORMIX SOFTWARE, INC.
 *
 *      THIS MATERIAL IS ALSO COPYRIGHTED AS AN UNPUBLISHED WORK UNDER
 *      SECTIONS 104 AND 408 OF TITLE 17 OF THE UNITED STATES CODE. 
 *      UNAUTHORIZED USE, COPYING OR OTHER REPRODUCTION IS PROHIBITED BY LAW.
 *
 *
 *  Title:       fgicfunc.h
 *  Description: 4GL C function header file
 *
 ***************************************************************************
 */

#ifndef IBM_I4GL_FGICFUNC_H
#define IBM_I4GL_FGICFUNC_H

typedef struct
    {
    char *cf_name;              /* name of function */
    int (*cf_ptr)(int);         /* pointer to the function */
    short cf_nargs;             /* number of arguments, < 0 means variable */
    } cfunc_t;

#endif /* IBM_I4GL_FGICFUNC_H */
```

We can discuss the erratic boxing comments another time.